# What is the source of this symbol?

Tags: identification-request, puja

[image]

What is the significance and source of the upper symbol? It is used on ghata at the time of worship and is also drawn on walls in Bengal. I do not know whether it is used in other parts of India.

Comment: its human 5 lines indicate pancha bhoota from which human body is made kalsha sthapa done using mantra to infuse diving presence inside kalasha that divine form is also having similar human like apperance as we are all made in the image of god..

Comment: @PrasannaR What is the scriptural source?

Comment: i dont have any i just read the image  i know kalasha and cocunut are required, meaning of kalasha sthapa also like that only. .May be you should the self answer  question what is the meaning kalasha sthapa rituals then you will get the exact meaning in the scripture and symbol.

Comment: What's the meaning of Ghata?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta ghata is the sanskrit term for kalasa that is consecrated in front of the priest to do the puja.

Comment: Oh! So, on this symbol kalash is placed right?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta This is drawn on the ghatas.